# Create single column index with future items and no title

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I have a document where I mention external references, sometimes more than once. I want an index of these mentions somewhere at the beginning of the document. And I do not want a title above. And I want it to be at the same width as the text (1 column)

I have tried this at first with `indextools` since this has the `afterindex` option. That makes the index work in that I can add index items later and they will show up. However, the `columns` options for `\makeindex` gets ignored, so it always shows as two columns and I want one. Also, I don't want the title, I just want to show the list where I call `\printindex`.

This is what the (minimized) code for that looks like:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{index_style.ist}
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[afterindex,nonewpage]{indextools}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeindex[
  name=references,
  title=References used,
  columns=1,
  options={-s index_style.ist}
]

\begin{document}

\noindent The following references are used in this document
\printindex[references]

\noindent add something to the index \index[references]{something}

\noindent add something else to the index \index[references]{something else}

\noindent add item to the index \index[references]{item}

\noindent add another item to the index \index[references]{another item}

\end{document}
```

Which yield this result (after two consecutive pdflatex runs):
[image]

Then I tried with `imakeidx`, with that the `columns` option works, so the list shows in one column, however, now I am no longer able to add index items afterwards. I may be able to fix that by just using makeindex and running makeindex between two pdflatex calls(?)

Anyway, maybe there's a better way to do this. The end result should look something like this:

[image]

Some notes:

- In the actual document, I want this reference **and** a (normal) glossary
- I may also want another one of this type of index (hence the named index)
- The actual document will be a lot larger, this MWE is indeed minimal in comparison
- The `indextools` solution got me closest, but:

  - I couldn't get it to go to just one column
  - I could not find how to hide the index title

Comment: Although I'd still like to learn how to get this going without running makeindex separately between pdflatex runs I have now gone that route. So I use just imakeidx with the working styles and run makeindex separately

Answer (score 0):

I think you are nearly there; in fact, you mention the solution yourself:

> I may be able to fix that by just using makeindex and running makeindex between two pdflatex calls(?)

If you would like to add an item to the index using the `makeidx` package, proceed as follows:

1. Add the item, e.g. `\index{item}`
2. Save the file
3. Compile your pdf file
4. Run `MakeIndex`
5. Compile your pdf file again